# Proving $m(E)<\infty\iff \forall\epsilon>0\exists\text{ compact }F\subset E: m(E)-m(F)<\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, lebesgue-measure

Is proving this question:

Proving $m(E)<\infty\iff \forall\epsilon>0\exists\text{ compact }F\subset E: m(E)-m(F)<\epsilon$.

The same as proving this question:

Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set of positive measure, and let $0 < \alpha < m(E)$ Prove that there exists a compact set $F\subset \mathbb{E}$ such that $m(F) = \alpha$.

If yes, why? if no, also why? What will be the difference in proving the second one as I know the proof of the first one?

Thanks!

Comment: Anyway, the first question is solved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140224/proving-me-infty-iff-forall-epsilon0-exists-text-compact-f-subset-e-me?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be a compact subset of $E$ such that $\alpha < m(K)<m(E)$.  Prove that $f(x)=m((-\infty, x]\cap K)$ is a continuous function and use IVP to prove the second result.

$f(y)-f(x)=m((x,y]\cap K) \leq m((x,y])=y-x$ for $x<y$ and this proves that $f$ is continuous. Also $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to -\infty$ and $f(x)\to m(K)$ as $ x\to \infty$. Now IVP tells you that $f$ attains all values between $0$ and $m(K)$, in particular the value $\alpha$.

Note that $(-\infty, x]\cap K$ is a closed subset of $K$ and hence it is compact.

Comment: Could you provide more details please about the proof of the second, How can I prove that the measure is a continuous function, my knowledge stopped at theorem 12 of Royden fourth edition, the continuity of the measure is in the next section "section 2.5".

Comment: Also, I edited my first question, as it used to contain a mistake ..... it is not $m(E) \ m(E) < \epsilon$ ... it is as corrected above now.

Comment: But the question needs the set $F$ to be compact.

Comment: How can I be sure that $E$ is bounded? because even if it has a finite measure it may be unbounded like the set of natural numbers for example.

Comment: Also how is $E$ a closed set?

Comment: I am sorry if this is a trivial question, but how is $f(y) - f(x)$ equals what you stated above ? by what property of measure?

Comment: is not $f$ is a set function that assigns to each measurable set a real number?

Comment: $(x,y]\cap K=(-\infty, y]\cap K \setminus  (-\infty, x]\cap K$.

Comment: But we have a difference in measures of those sets and not difference in the sets.

Comment: Also, you used the idea that between any 2 real numbers there is a compact set ..... how can I prove this fact?

Comment: for you last comment .... did you use the excision property of measure when you did this?